# Problem with cocoapods : CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have try to install pods and I have this error

```
[!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: 403 <!DOCTYPE html> 
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
... (lot of code seems html)
```

What I did :

1. `open the terminal`
2. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
3. `access to my folder where I have the xcodeproj with command cd`
4. `pod init`
5. here is my podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Clinique Barber' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Clinique Barber
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end
```

6.save and go to terminal: command `pod install`
And I have the error...

I have try to uninstall cocoapods completely.
Try to install cocoapods with homebrew.
Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> set command line tools
Try to use `arch -x86_64 pod install`
Try to use `pod repo remove trunk`

Nothing is working.

I have already use cocoapods with the steps above and it works fine.

But today I don't know why, it don't works.

What I can do please ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay it works now. It seems cocoapods has a problem for a moment but it fixed.